# Unable to select checkbox in datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have the following code in my c# windows application where I am trying to insert a checkbox corresponding to each row. When i click a button outside the selected rows should be deleted. But i am not able to select the checkbox using this code.

```
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
OleDbCommand SQLQuery = new OleDbCommand();
DataTable data = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
SQLQuery.Connection = null;
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = null;
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear(); 

SQLQuery.CommandText = sqlQueryString;
SQLQuery.Connection = database;
data = new DataTable();
dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQLQuery);
dataAdapter.Fill(data);
dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true; // remove the null line
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 340;
dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 55;          
// insert checkbox button into datagridview
deleteck = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
deleteck.HeaderText = "delete";     
deleteck.Width = 80;
deleteck.ReadOnly = false;         
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, deleteck);
```

Could anyone help me to figure out what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this solution:

```
    dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    For Each dc as DataColumn in dt.Columns
        dc.ReadOnly = true
    Next

    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true; 
    // dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = true;
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 340;
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 55;          
    deleteck = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    deleteck.HeaderText = "delete";     
    deleteck.Width = 80;
    deleteck.ReadOnly = false;         
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, deleteck);
```

In this way, only the checkbox is editable, while the rest of the columns collection is marked as readonly at the datasource level.

Answer (score 0):

it was a mistake on my code.

```
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
```

when i just commented the above line it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You must check the Enable Editing checkbox in the DataGridView Task list. here is the screen shot

[image]